Amazon Bedrock - security token included in the request is invalid
I'm trying to invoke a ML model with amazon bedrock, I verified that I used the correct credintials to connect to my AWS accout, i imported boto3, I even tried to list my S3 buckets and it worked. I also have access to this model I'm trying to use, but i keep to get the same result, what can be the problem ?
My code:
bedrock_runtime = boto3.client(
    service_name="bedrock-runtime",
    region_name="eu-west-3"
)

prompt="Hello"

kwargs = {
 "modelId": "amazon.titan-text-express-v1",
 "contentType": "application/json",
 "accept": "application/json",
 "body": "{\"inputText\":\"" + prompt + "\",\"textGenerationConfig\":{\"maxTokenCount\":8192,\"stopSequences\":[],\"temperature\":0,\"topP\":1}}"
}

response = bedrock_runtime.invoke_model(**kwargs)
response

the issue:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
   1019             )
   1020             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
-> 1021             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
   1022         else:
   1023             return parsed_response

ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the InvokeModel operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

what do you recommend me to do ?

It's basically saying that it has been given invalid credentials -- is the code running on an EC2 instance or on your own computer? When you say that you listed S3, did you do it as part of the code snippet you displayed? If not, how & where did you do it?
